# Limitar registros por número de repetições

Tags: sql

Eu tenho uma consulta da seguinte forma, e gostaria de filtrar pelo COUNT

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS QTD,
       Nome,
       Cpf
FROM Funcionarios
WHERE QTD >= 2
GORUP BY Nome, Cpf
```

Comment: explique melhor, de um exemplo de resultado. Você quer recuperar nomes e cpf duplicados?

Answer (score 4):

Tente ajustar sua query para filtrar após agrupar os dados com a cláusula **Having**:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS QTD,
       Nome,
       Cpf
  FROM Funcionarios
 GROUP BY Nome, Cpf
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
```